# CRC error in data packets

Tags: crc16

I am getting a CRC error (on HDLC layer) for H224 data packets on destination for the packets that have been received from the source. The source sends 3 types of packets: audio (AAC-LD) packets, video packets and data packets. But while receiving the data packets, source throws CRC error on the packets received. Could anyone help in what could be the reason for this CRC error?

Comment: The reason that the CRC is there is to detect errors in transport. So you have detected an error in transport.

Comment: Hi Mark,It would be very helpful if you Could explain this in a bit detail.

Comment: That's all there is to it. It's up to you to figure out why the packets at the destination are not the same as the packets that emanated from the source.